# Error in Playing video in videoview with tab (android)

Tags: android, android-tabs, android-video-player, android-videoview

Hey when i go to play video in videoview, the app is crashing.

**Error:**

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window --
>   token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@536f91ec is
>   not valid; is your activity running?

Please help me

```
video=(Videoview)findViewById(R.id.video);
Intent in= getIntent();
String res=in.getStringExtra("video");
Log.e("video", ""+res);

MediaController controller = new MediaController(Video_Player.this);
video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(res));

video.setMediaController(controller);
video.requestFocus();
video.start();
```

Comment: try this. MediaController controller = new MediaController(getApplicationContext());

Comment: but error in video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(res));

Comment: in which method are you executing this code ?

Comment: oncreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)